# Android Deep Link: How to open different activities with intent-filters in manifest?

Tags: android, regex, deep-linking

I have setup intent-filters for 3 urls

-> https://www.example.com -> open Activity A

```
<intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="Appname" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/^/?$"
                    android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

-> https://www.example.com/internships or  -> https://www.example.com/internships/ open Activity B

```
<intent-filter android:label="Awign">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    android:pathPattern="/internships^/?$"
                    android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

-> https://www.example.com/internships/{some_path_param}  -> open Activity C

```
<intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="Appname" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/^/?$"
                    android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Activity A and C open as expected, how can I achieve the result that I want for activity B.

Also, how can I allow deep linking in chrome browser searches? For example, if I have these three URLs in the search result.
I am not talking about typing the URL in the address bar, just the search results. As mentioned in other questions, typing results in address bar won't open app anyways

Answer (score 0):

Using [Branch's deep linking SDK](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking) you should be able to simplify this process by adding `$deeplink_path`. This will allow you to handle deep activity without relying on regexes.

To set this up, your manifest would simply include this:

```
   <activity android:name="com.yourapp.your_activity">
         <!-- App Link your activity to Branch links-->
         <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="yourapp-alternate.app.link" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="yourapp.app.link" />
         </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then to handle the link, you'd have something like this:

```
Branch branch = Branch.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
branch.initSession(new BranchReferralInitListener(){
    @Override
    public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
        if (error == null) {
            // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
            // params will be empty if no data found
            // ... insert custom logic here ...
        } else {
            Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
        }
    }
}, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
```